# Cloud Functions for Firebase: functions.pubsub.topic('testTopic').onPublish not called

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I've copied this code snippet from the official documentation of cloud functions:

```
exports.helloPubSub = functions.pubsub.topic('testTopic').onPublish(event => {
    return console.log("test topic event data", event.data) 
})
```

The topic exists, the function is deployed successfully; if I send a message to it, the message arrives to the devices, BUT this function does not get called.

Anyone some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase (Google) Cloud Messaging and Google Cloud Pub/Sub are different messaging systems, as [explained here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq):

> Both are systems to deliver messages, but Google Cloud Messaging is
>   used to deliver messages to and from end-user devices, while Google
>   Cloud Pub/Sub is used to communicate between servers. Google Cloud
>   Messaging is designed to scale to a very large number of delivery end
>   points, but has low throughput (messages per second per channel).
>   Pub/Sub does not have limits on throughput and has a more generic API.

Although they share the concept of topics, a message sent to an FCM topic will not trigger a [Pub/Sub Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events).