# How to use FCM sendToTopic from a cloud function using the admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I need to break up a time consuming process into multiple cloud functions, because in total it would take more then 9mins (the max execution time). To do this I would like one (entry) cloud function, triggered by a pub/sub topic, to write messages to other topics, which in turn trigger the other pub/sub cloud functions.

I am testing these via `firebase experimental:functions:shell`. Triggering the entry function is not a problem, but when that functions calls `admin.messaging().sendToTopic(...)` I get the following error:

> An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make
>   sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper
>   permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for
>   setup instructions.

I am not sure if this is because I'm testing it locally, but I couldn't find any easy way to send a message to a topic. The firebase console has the "notifications" section where you can easily format and send messages, but these only seem to target client apps (ios/android/web).

I can't find anything in the docs about configuring credentials for FCM use in cloud functions. I am using the standard credentials. My functions have no problem writing to my Firestore instance for example.

The [docs for using FCM in the admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/) don't seem to mention anything about this either.

Comment: An FCM message will not trigger a Pub/Sub cloud function.  See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44545878/4815718).  There is a [detailed example here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/pubsub) showing how to send a Pub/Sub message.  I've not used, but I _think_ that is what you need.

Comment: Aha! Damn all this documentation overlap across the firebase and google cloud platforms is confusing for beginners. I have been reading so much but links in sections kept referring to each other. I never ended up in the FAQ there... Do you mind copying your answer to here? I think the question is not a duplicate, but the answer is still fitting anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase (Google) Cloud Messaging and Google Cloud Pub/Sub are different messaging systems, as [explained here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq):

> Both are systems to deliver messages, but Google Cloud Messaging is
>   used to deliver messages to and from end-user devices, while Google
>   Cloud Pub/Sub is used to communicate between servers. Google Cloud
>   Messaging is designed to scale to a very large number of delivery end
>   points, but has low throughput (messages per second per channel).
>   Pub/Sub does not have limits on throughput and has a more generic API.

Although they share the concept of topics, a message sent to an FCM topic will not trigger a [Pub/Sub Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events).

You can publish a Pub/Sub message from a Cloud Function using `@google-cloud/pubsub`.  The [documentation is here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/pubsub/0.15.0/pubsub).

The two functions below demonstrate publishing and receiving a simple string message.

```
const pubsub = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')();

exports.testWrite = functions.database.ref('/test').onWrite(event => {
   var topic = pubsub.topic('test-topic');

  // Publish a message to the topic.
  var publisher = topic.publisher();
  var message = Buffer.from('Hello World!');

  return publisher.publish(message);
});

exports.helloPubSub = functions.pubsub.topic('test-topic').onPublish(event => {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(event.data.data, 'base64');
  console.log('message=', buffer.toString('utf8'));
  return null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bob! That was super helpful.